# String pre-processing step, to answer further queries in O(1) time

Tags: string, algorithm

A string is given to you and it contains characters consisting of only 3 characters. Say, x y z. 
There will be million queries given to you. 
Query format: x z i j

Now in this we need to find all possible different substrings which begins with x and ends in z. i and j denotes the lower and upper bound of the range where the substring must lie. It should not cross this.

My Logic:-

1. Read the string. Have 3 arrays which will store the count of x y z respectively, for i=0 till strlen
2. Store the indexes of each characters separately in 3 more arrays. xlocation[], ylocation[], zlocation[]
3. Now, accordingly to the query, (a b i j) find all the indices of b within the range i and j.
4. Calculate the answer, for each index of b and sum it to get the result.

Is it possible to pre-process this string before the query? So, like that it takes O(1) time to answer the query.

Comment: Do you need to print the substrings, or just count them?

Comment: How can it take O(1) time to provide potentially O(n^2) values?

Comment: @IVlad: just count them.

Comment: I've thought of a solution involving linear-time preprocessing and linear space usage that enables constant-time queries, but before I describe it, I'd like to see some evidence that this isn't just a homework or competition question.

Comment: Hint to @IVlad: your (now-deleted) solution was *very* close!  Think about how to count the strings that kraskevich pointed out... ;-)

Comment: @j_random_hacker:  It was a homework that my friend gave me last week. I'll be glad if you can share your linear time an space algorithm.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - I got it I think. I could've used my `count` array for it. Ah well, should have pushed a little harder :).

Answer (score 1):

As the others suggested, you can do this with a divide and conquer algorithm.

Optimal substructure:
If we are given a left half of the string and a right half and we know how many substrings there are in the left half and how many there are in the right half then we can add the two numbers together. We will be undercounting by all the strings that begin in the left and end in the right. This is simply the number of x's in the left substring multiplied by the number of z's in the right substring.

Therefore we can use a recursive algorithm.

This would be a problem however if we tried to solve for everything single i and j combination as the bottom level subproblems would be solved many many times.

You should look into implementing this with a dynamic programming algorithm keeping track of substrings in range i,j, x's in range i,j, and z's in range i,j.

Comment: What an elegant explanation Sir Alex Wang. :) :D

Comment: This may TLE because the time complexity of this algo is T(n) = 2*T(n) + c which is O(n) and n can be million and queries are million too. It can be avoided only if we can save it an 2D array which this dp requires but it will give an error because of the high memory usage. I think @IVLAd solution was fitting the constraints.